# I cannot make a unit test for controller in C# .NET

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, backend

```
using employmently_be.Data.Models;
using employmently_be.DbContexts;
using employmently_be.Entities;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using NUnit.Framework;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using employmently_be.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Moq;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

namespace Employmently.Tests.Controllers
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class RegistrationControllerTests
    {
        private RegistrationController _registrationController;
        private UserManager<User> _userManager;
        private SignInManager<User> _signInManager;
        private ILogger<EmailSender> _logger;
        private DbContextOptions<dbContext> _dbContextOptions;
        private IConfiguration _configMock;
        private IOptions<AuthMessageSenderOptions> _authMessageSenderOptions;


        private SignInManager<User> GetSignInManager(UserManager<User> userManager)
        {
            var httpContextAccessorMock = new Mock<IHttpContextAccessor>();
            var userClaimsPrincipalFactory = new UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<User>(userManager, null);
            var optionsAccessor = new Mock<IOptions<IdentityOptions>>();
            var logger = Mock.Of<ILogger<SignInManager<User>>>();
            var schemes = Mock.Of<IAuthenticationSchemeProvider>();
            var confirmation = Mock.Of<IUserConfirmation<User>>();

            return new SignInManager<User>(userManager, httpContextAccessorMock.Object, userClaimsPrincipalFactory, optionsAccessor.Object, logger, schemes, confirmation);
        }


        [SetUp]
        public void SetUp()
        {

            var dbContext = new dbContext();

            var userStore = new UserStore<User>(dbContext);
            _userManager = new UserManager<User>(userStore, null, new PasswordHasher<User>(), null, null, null, null, null, null);

            var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();
            var contextAccessor = new HttpContextAccessor { HttpContext = httpContext };
            var claimsFactory = new UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<User>(_userManager, null);
            var optionsAccessor = Options.Create(new IdentityOptions());
            var logger = new Mock<ILogger<SignInManager<User>>>().Object;
            _signInManager = new SignInManager<User>(_userManager, contextAccessor, claimsFactory, optionsAccessor, logger, null, null);

            _logger = new LoggerFactory().CreateLogger<EmailSender>();

            _registrationController = new RegistrationController(
                dbContext,
                _userManager,
                _configMock,
                _logger,
                _authMessageSenderOptions
                );
        }

        [Test]
        public async Task Register_ValidModel_ReturnsSuccessResult()
        {
            // Arrange
            var model = new RegisterDto
            {
                Email = "testuser@test.com",
                Password = "Test1234!",
                ConfirmPassword = "Test1234!"
            };

            // Act
            var result = await _registrationController.Register(model);

            // Assert
            Assert.IsNotNull(result);
            Assert.IsInstanceOf<OkResult>(result);

        }
    }
}
```

hello i have been trying to make a test for my registration controller in my application but i always cant seem to make it happen, this is my last version of the code and i got this error:

```
System.ArgumentNullException : Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'optionsAccessor')
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserClaimsPrincipalFactory`1..ctor(UserManager`1 userManager, IOptions`1 optionsAccessor)
   at Employmently.Tests.Controllers.RegistrationControllerTests.SetUp() in C:\Employmently\Employmently\employmently-be\employmently-be-test\UnitTest1.cs:line 57
```

Can someone help me to repair it so i can test the functionalities? I think the problem is in the making of the registration controller.

Comment: The error message is quite clear. In your call to `new UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<User>(_userManager, null)` the second parameter (options) must not be null.

Comment: Ok, now i have bad request, which i see from here :             Assert.IsInstanceOf<OkResult>(result);
how can i see where the problem comes from from the source code?

Comment: You can use the Debugger to step through your code.

Comment: System.NotSupportedException : No IUserTwoFactorTokenProvider<TUser> named 'Default' is registered.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1.GenerateUserTokenAsync(TUser user, String tokenProvider, String purpose)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(TUser user)


now i think i have a problem with two factor token provider

Comment: You could also mock `IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<User>` like the other interfaces.

Comment: System.NotSupportedException : No IUserTwoFactorTokenProvider<TUser> named 'Default' is registered.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1.GenerateUserTokenAsync(TUser user, String tokenProvider, String purpose)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(TUser user)
   at employmently_be.Controllers.RegistrationController.Register(RegisterDto rdt) in C:\Employmently\Employmently\employmently-be\employmently-be\Controllers\IdentityControllers\RegistrationController.cs:line 67
   at

Comment: You shouldn't really test controllers. You should test business logic.

Comment: @VladDX and it is in the controllers, how should i test its functions in which it is the business logic?

Comment: @AleksandarHristov, controllers should be a thin layer to facilitate an entry point for a request. Controller just routes a request and parses it, straight after that it should pass it to the Business Logic (aka "Service Layer"). Then you tests services, not controllers.